# BETWEEN for columns in Kohana Database

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

How to specify

```
NOW() BETWEEN col1 AND col2
```

using Kohana Database?

```
$this->where(new Database_Expression('NOW()'), 'BETWEEN', array('col1', 'col2'));
```

obviously treats the values as a string literals, not a column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

<s>`$this->where(DB::expr('NOW() BETWEEN col1 AND col2'));`</s>

Edit:

`$this->where('NOW()', 'BETWEEN', DB::expr('col1 AND col2'));`

Comment: `where` expects 3 arguments, btw there is no `DB::expr` method in Kohana3

Comment: Yep, that works too. Will check your answer in a couple of minutes

Comment: @zerkms since when is there no `DB::expr` in Ko3?

Comment: @Kemo: it was my fault - and it was too late to edit the comment when I realized it :-(

Answer (score 1):

Read some code and got it:

```
$this->where(null, null, new Database_Expression('NOW() BETWEEN col1 AND col2'));
```